# Mongoose unit test

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing

I have the following mongoose unit test. The console log line in the article.save() callback prints out the assigned _id attributed to the entity after it has been saved from the database. However whenever I put in a breakpoint on that line or indeed on the first line in the corresponding unit test, the entity isn't available in the articles collection?

Can anyone explain why this should be? I'm struggling to make sense of this and would appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Mark.

```
var app = require('../../server.js'),
    should = require('should'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = mongoose.model('User'),
    Article = mongoose.model('Article');

var user, article;

describe('Article Model Unit Tests:', function () {

beforeEach(function (done) {

    user = new User({
        firstName: 'Full',
        lastName: 'Last',
        displayName: 'Full Name',
        email: 'test@test.com',
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    });

    user.save(function () {
        article = new Article({
            title: 'Article Title',
            content: 'Content Article',
            user: user
        });

        article.save(function (err, savedArticle) {
            console.log(savedArticle._id);
        });
    });

    done();
});

describe('Testing the save method', function () {
    it('Should be able to save without problems', function () {
        article.save(function (err) {
            should.not.exist(err);
        });
    });

    it('Should not be able to save without title', function () {
        article.title = '';

        article.save(function (err) {
            should.exist(err);
        });
    });
});

afterEach(function(done) {
    Article.remove(function(){
        User.remove(function(){
            done();
        });
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think The done call should be moved inside of article.save

As it is now, done()will almost always be called before the two saves complete, if done was moved then the beforeeach block would only finish when both saves have completed

Comment: Thanks a million dm03514! I've no idea why that makes a difference though? What does the done() method accomplish? Does it effectively flush the mongoose model? The user never saves ever neither in the unit tests but does in the application.. .
Sorry lots of questions there but I'm trying to get started with MEAN and there's more questions than answers at this stage.

Comment: If I remove the done() altogether then the article IS available in the MongoDB at the console line.

If I place the done() after the article.save() yet inside the user.save() the article is unavailable? 

Any help here would be appreciated. I'm coming from a Spring/Hibernate/Oracle background so my assumptions are possible tempered by that.

Comment: The param, conventionally called done, is strange, adding it as a parameter to beforeEach or it marks the operation as async, if you add done in an it and do not call done the test case will error.  Beforeeach could be weird because if it doesn't throw an error it wi timeout, then go to execute your it, perhaps giving the impression that everything is working ok

Comment: Done doesn't  directly haveanything to do with mongoose per se, it just allows you to signal to the test framework when an async operation has completed https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining that to me Dm03514 I really appreciate it!